# In homebrew, how can I know xargs belongs to the findutil package?

Tags: linux, package, homebrew, gnu-findutils

I'm on a mac and I don't want to use the builtin `xargs` utility. Because it's different with the gnu `xargs`. After google around I found `xargs` belongs to the `findutils` package in homebrew and I can install it with a simple command `brew install findutils`. My question is, it there a simpler way to identify `xargs` belongs to `findutils`?

Thanks.

Comment: `which xargs` will show the path. /usr/bin/xargs on mac is the system bsd. you can add this to your path to ensure xargs from brew findutils: `PATH="$(brew --prefix findutils)/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"; export PATH`

Comment: as of today, you can find xargs in findutils by finding this question as the top result on google.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`brew search --desc xargs`

will give the result

`findutils: Collection of GNU find, xargs, and locate`

The `--desc` option is required to search in the descriptions.
It does not search in the list of files provided by each package. I believe this may be impossible because brew's formula don't include this list of files.